# Howto implement horizontal accordion in java?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, accordion, jface

What is the best way to implement horizontal accordion in Java?
I am using Swing, JFace and Eclipse RCP.

[Here](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/) is an example of a horizontal accordion, implemented in JavaScript!

Comment: What graphical framework are you using? Swing? SWT? JavaFX? GWT? AWT?

Comment: Oh yeah: I am using Swing, JFace and Eclipse RCP.

Comment: And after looking at the example of JavaScript implementation, you most definitely tried to implement it yourself with your Java UI toolkit. What were the problems you have encountered?

Comment: Did not try to implement my own yet, wanted to ask first for me not to reinvent teh wheel

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you are going to use SWT, not Swing. If I'm right you can take a look at [Nebula Project](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) or org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandBar. I haven seen yet a Horizontal accordion for swt, but taking a look in the code you might get an idea how to achieve it. Another solution would be to use a Browser in order to use the js accordion. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/) is an Browser tutorial, that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question with using Swing has already raised in this topic [Accordion for Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944256/accordion-for-swing)

Example with vertical implementation can be found [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=236). I think it's not too hard to implement horizontal.